# C# MVC Android URL encoded parameters

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple website I am playing around with, that takes in an email and password to log in. This all works fine on a PC browser, and on apple phones / tablets.

However, droid devices will not log in. I routed my test phone via my pc and used fiddler to look at the http traffic, and Android is encoding email addresses, so instead of foo@here.com I am seeing foo%40here.com, and so my server side validation is failing as this is not a valid email address.

The easy way to my mind of detecting this is to simply look at the email string before I validate it, and look for the %40 symbol. But if android is goign to urlencode everything by default, this could give me issues further on down the line, and having to examin strings, and guess whether a % is part of some url encoding, or a genuine percentage will become a problem.

So is there an attribute or filter I can apply to my method so that the framework will unencode it as required, or do I need to handle this on a case by case basis?

Comment: That's odd, I would like more info. Can you post the code that sends the attributes? On the other hand, I suppose you are sending the info using GET, why don't you use POST? POST is the recommended method when performing a login.

Comment: Just use one of the c# decoding utilities and you'll be fine.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman the form is set to post, and so far its just a boilerplate html form. Its just 'droid thats doing this

Comment: @RobertMoskal but I can't decode everything, as what if later on I want the user to send me data that legitimately holds percentages, and they use the site on a PC? I'd have the risk that I'd get a match to URL encoding, and decode something accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

try by adding `("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");` line in your request before sending request
like this `request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");`

se the example

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Constants.mWebURL+Constants.mSendBloodReq);
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        // adding paramaters
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",params[0]));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",params[1]));
                   UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters,"UTF-8");
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(request);
        //getting response
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

My Method on the controller wasn't decorated with a [HttpPost] attribute. That seems to have fixed it for me